# View CVS history in Eclipse when using both CVS and Git

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have both a CVS and a Git repository for one project.

When I right-click into the editor and choose "Team" in the context menu I get Git context only. Also in the Eclipse menu Window -> Show View -> Team/History the Git history view is opened.

At least in the first case (editor context menu Team -> Show in history) I would like to navigate to the CVS history view.

The background is, that I must use CVS remotely but use Git for local versioning.

It seems to me that Eclipse is preferring Git over CVS. Is there a way to change this behaviour?